# Установить placeholder в dropdownlist динамически

Tags: reactjs, placeholder

Необходимо после выбранных значений в выпадающем списке по нажатию на кнопку устанавливать дефолтное состояние компонента: без выбранных элементов и с placeholder-надписью.

Как это можно сделать? 
Или чтобы можно было очистить выбранное значение в выпадающем списке. Я попробовал обратиться через refs к компоненту, добраться до значения value и изменить его на пустую строку, но тогда происходит перезапись значения в компоненте. А это мне не нужно. Нужно лишь, чтобы само поле очистилось, а все значения списка сохранились.

Comment: Такие вопросы должны сопровождатся кодом, чтобы было с чем помогать.